# What is stored in HDFS and why map-reduce compute so fast when Titan execute queries ？

Tags: database, hadoop, graph, hbase, titan

I am learning Titan now. I used Titan with HBase in remote mode.

There are three questions confused me now. I described them in the below:

1. In TinkerPop3 Documentation, it said "The results of any OLAP operation are stored in HDFS accessible via hdfs." But now I used Titan for OLTP, and what is stored in HDFS in this situation?
2. When we used Titan connect HBase success(by Java IDE), we can see table created in HBase shell and scan the content. What is the meaning of content 'column' in table？ Are they represented the vertex id in graph?
3. When I tested performance of Titan, I observed the speed of queries faster than normal map-reduce job. Why Titan can achieved it? In Titan-Documentation, they said Titan engine "Titan-Hadoop" using parallel map-reduce model.Can I get more detailed introduction about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The Titan [architecture diagram](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/arch-overview.html) helps show the difference between OLTP and OLAP usage. See the right side of the architecture diagram: TinkerPop API - Gremlin. OLTP is the most common Titan usage, no matter which backend storage you select (Cassandra, HBase, BerkeleyDB). When you do an OLTP query with Titan-HBase, nothing is stored in HDFS. In fact, HDFS/Hadoop is not required at all for OLTP with Titan-HBase.
2. When scanning the contents of the Titan table in HBase, you will find the serialized representation of the graph. Titan uses data compression techniques on keys/columns/values, so you will find that the data isn't human readable. You can read more about the specifics of the storage layout in the [Titan docs](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/data-model.html).
3. See answer to #1, and you probably have been running OLTP queries. Hadoop-style OLAP graph processing is done via a graph computer. It uses the [TitanHBaseInputFormat](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/tree/1.0.0/titan-hadoop-parent/titan-hadoop-core/src/main/java/com/thinkaurelius/titan/hadoop/formats/hbase) to read data in from the backend storage, then uses a TinkerPop Graph Computer ([Spark or Giraph](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.0.1-incubating/#_olap_hadoop_gremlin)) to run the OLAP job. See the left side of the architecture diagram above: GremlinGraphComputer. There is also some documentation of this in the [Titan docs](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/titan-hadoop-tp3.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I read your answer and understand it. It means that when we execute OLTP queries, they transfer to OLAP jobs to return results ? Hadoop have two vital parts HDFS & Map-Reduce.If HDFS stored null and no map-reduce process in graph compute, why Titan engine named 'Titan-Hadoop' ? Because Titan apply Hadoop-style OLAP graph processing and stored the results of OLAP operation in HDFS ?

Comment: By the way, I have been solved connection error according to your last answer, thanks a lot.

Comment: OLTP and OLAP query processing flows are completely separate. When you execute an OLTP query, your request goes through the Titan API to the storage backend. Hadoop is not involved from a Titan perspective, although HBase may be using HDFS, if you have it configured as a fully distributed cluster.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I confused the role which Hadoop performed in OLTP and OLAP before I read your response. I get it now.  An extra question about OLTP is that why Titan API can support OLTP queries so fast ?  Could I get more introduction about this problem? I had believed that the reason is parallel map-reduce. But now my view seems incorrect.